# violating mapKeysMonotonic precondition

Tags: json, haskell, dictionary

I want to send some JSON that will contain a mapping from (Database.Persist.Sql) Keys to values. The obvious solution would be to use a `Map (Key x) v`, but this is not an instance of `ToJSON`.

Some alternatives are:

- don't use JSON, use something better (like [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn))
- don't return a `Map k v`, return a `Map Text v` (but here I'd lose some type information)
- `type JsonKey = Text`, and `Map JsonKey v`, but this is not really any better
- define my own `ToJSON` instance.

The latter seems to be the one that will require less changes, and the cleaner one.

Also, be aware that I only need the `ToJSON` instance, not the `FromJSON`, so I don't need the whole roundtripping.

So, this is what I want to write:

```
import Database.Persist.Sql (Key)
instance ToJSON (ToJSON v => (Map (Key a) v))
```

Assuming that `Key` has a friendly `Show` instance (it doesn't, but this is just a detail)... I was about to write:

```
instance ToJSON (ToJSON v => (Map (Key a) v)) where
  toJSON m = toJSON $ mapKeysMonotonic show m
```

but I immeditately realized that this is bad (Keys are just like integers):

```
> 9 < 10
True
> "9" < "10"
False
```

This violates the `mapKeysMonotonic` precondition.

Now, in the meanwhile, I can just use `mapKeys`... but I tried to think, what's the risk in violating this? `mapKeys` is obviously less efficient. And I understand how this might be premature optimization.

But I'd still like to understand in which way this could break down... or if it's indeed safe for my limited use case. The only thing I care about is if no values are lost. I don't care about their order.

Now, [this is `instance (ToJSON v) => ToJSON (M.Map String v)`](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/1c25679039513c3ff/Data/Aeson/Types/Instances.hs#L630). It converts a `Data.Map` to a `Data.HashMap`

Which relies on [`mapHashKeyVals`](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/1c25679039513c/Data/Aeson/Functions.hs#L22)... which uses `Data.Map.foldrWithKey`

I also thought of using an `HashMap (Key x) v`, to avoid either a `N*log(N)` computation or `mapKeysMonotonic`. But I'd have the define the ToJSON instance nonetheless, and apparently there's no `mapKeys` for `HashMap` (understandably, since this would require to recompute all the hashes, but I'm not sure if this would actually be more expensive than a `mapKeys`)

Now, I tried this simple example:

```
> mapKeysMonotonic show $ fromList [(10,"a"), (9, "b"), (99, "c"), (100, "d")]
fromList [("9","b"),("10","a"),("99","c"),("100","d")]
```

and since `show` returns a distinct `String` for each distinct `Int`, obviously no values are lost. The Map now is probably unbalanced... but what are the consequences? I guess that `union`, `difference`, `intersection` might misbehave... but what about traversal and folds? Would these still retain all the elements in all cases?

PS: I just realized that another possible solution maybe could be to define `instance ToJSON (ToJSON v => [(Key x, v)])` and convert it to `Map` on the inside... but I guess this would be an overlapping instance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Map.showTree` to inspect the binary tree structure of the maps. The `mapKeysMonotonic` function keeps the same tree order and just replaces the nodes, and so any accessor that involves searching the tree will give wrong results.

Traversals that don't search will quite possibly work, but using maps like this violates the logic of the data structure which is a recipe for confusion and bugs.

To define your `ToJSON` instance, you don't need to build an intermediate map; you can use `foldrWithKey` to construct a `Value` directly. Note that the `Object` constructor in Aeson is just `HashMap Text Value`. The fold itself is O(n) and inserting into a `HashMap` is (practically) constant time. Something like this:

```
instance ToJSON v => ToJSON (Map (Key a) v) where
  toJSON = Object . Map.foldrWithKey f mempty
    where f = HashMap.insert . Text.pack . show
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not guarantee that the function is monotonic, you can use

```
mapKeys :: Ord k2 => (k1 -> k2) -> Map k1 a -> Map k2 a
```

This is `O(n*log n)`, so it's a bit slower than `mapKeysMonotonic` which is `O(n)`. Still, it's only a `log n` factor slower, so it might be good enough.

In any case, I would not violate the `Map` invariant: you might cause elements to disappear from the map, or be duplicated.